# objective c :get date from date offset value

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, offset

I have dates stored in my `MSSql` database as an offset value of the date. For example: `8/2/14 12:25 AM` is stored as `41853.0178824074`.

How can I get the date back from its offset value?
You can get this value easily by converting any `float` number in excel to date.

Thanks.

Comment: Offset from *what* date (i.e what is the epoch)?

Comment: in MSExcel this offset is calculated from 1/1/1900  12:00:00 AM(mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: The reference date for an NSDate object is 1/1/2001.  You simply need to calculate once the number of seconds in the interval 1900 to 2001 and then add/subtract time intervals on NSDate -- a one-line operation.

Comment: @HotLicks Not true as Excel has a bug where it thinks 1900 is a leap year and this bug must be replicated in the conversion code.

Comment: @Droppy - You can account for that in the constant and only have to special-case dates in 1900.

Comment: @HotLicks I challenge you to do it in one line, however.

Comment: @Droppy -- Not really that hard -- compare the incoming value to a constant for Feb 28 1900 23:59.59.999.  If greater, subtract off 24 hours.  Add the "big" constant.  `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(srdDate > Feb2800Secs ? srcDate - Feb2800Secs : srcDate) - BigConstant]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a working example of creating an `NSDate` object from an Excel offset date, including code to workaround the leap year bug present in Excel:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSDate *dateFromExcelSerialDate(double serialdate)
{
    if (serialdate > 31 + 28)
        serialdate -= 1.0;      // Fix Excel bug where it thinks 1900 is a leap year
    const NSTimeInterval numberOfSecondsInOneDay = 86400;
    NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval = serialdate * numberOfSecondsInOneDay; //number of days
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    [calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];

    NSDateComponents *excelBaseDateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [excelBaseDateComps setYear:1900];
    [excelBaseDateComps setMonth:1];
    [excelBaseDateComps setDay:0];
    [excelBaseDateComps setHour:0];
    [excelBaseDateComps setMinute:0];
    [excelBaseDateComps setSecond:0];
    [excelBaseDateComps setTimeZone:timeZone];
    NSDate *excelBaseDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:excelBaseDateComps];

    NSDate *inputDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval
                                           sinceDate:excelBaseDate];

    return inputDate;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            char *endptr;
            double d = strtod(argv[i], &endptr);
            if (endptr && *endptr == '\0') {
                NSDate *date = dateFromExcelSerialDate(d);
                NSLog(@"%@", date);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Ignoring invalid double value '%s'", argv[i]);
            }
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

It's written as a Foundation command line utility and compiled using:

```
clang -DDEBUG=1 -g -fobjc-arc -Wall -o excelnsdate excelnsdate.m -framework Foundation
```

This is what it produces with the values you supply in your question:

```
./excelnsdate 41853.0178824074
2014-08-04 11:18:04.766 excelnsdate[91305:507] 2014-08-02 00:25:45 +0000
```

Comment: thanks dude .. works like a charm .. i was under the impression that objective c would have some api to do this conversion .. but looks like the logic has to be written ..                                       Thanks again..

Comment: @shirjai You're welcome.  Please note there was an `NSDateFormatter` object in the code which was used for debugging and wasn't stripped-out.  I have update the code with it removed.  Also a dateformatter object *should* be used to print the final date, not `NSLog` directly as that can lead to timezone confusion (see `[NSDate description]` for details).